# Trying to automate scanning for flash embed links on other domains

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I tried this code to pull website but when I test it, the alert box doesn't run.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
$.get( "https://crossorigin.me/https://google.com", function( data ) {
alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you expand on *"doesn't work"*?

Comment: When I run the script the alert box simply doesn't run. Also, I can't access the console because I am using a school computer under a G Suite that blocks developer tools.

Comment: Do you have jquery loaded?

Comment: Yes, I have it loaded.

Comment: Please provide the full body of the GET request including the headers, you can find it for example [chrome devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/). The crossorigin.com requires Origin header to be present

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/), try implementing the `.fail` method to see what went wrong.

```
var jqxhr = $.get( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
  });
 
// Perform other work here ...
 
// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.always(function() {
  alert( "second finished" );
});
```

Also the author of [crossorigin.com](https://corsproxy.github.io/) warns that

> PLEASE DO NOT USE THE PROXY ON A PRODUCTION SITE.
>
> I cannot guarantee the stability of the service, and you will probably experience service interruptions.

Comment: Please provide the full body of the GET request including the headers, you can find it for example chrome devtools. The crossorigin.com requires Origin header to be present

Comment: I cannot use dev tools, my computer is on a G-Suite that blocks them

Comment: That is a [private subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), I can't access that. And what do you mean about the g-suite blocking dev tools. Fire up chrome/firefox and press f12.

Comment: Are you trying to bypass a security feature and or a firewall at your school?

Comment: I'm on a locked down chromebook

Comment: I am doing penetration testing for IT

Comment: Where do I input headers?